Underlying model ANOVA and Kruskal-Wallis
Is the underlying model for one way ANOVA ($Y_{ij}= u + t_i + E_{ij}$) the exact same for Kruskal-Wallis test since KW is the non-parametric anova equivalent or does it have a different model?

I don't think it makes much sense to talk about a model for Kruskal-Wallis as it works with ranks, so there is (e.g.) no notion of an error term on the scale of the data.

The standard null model $H_0$ for Kruskal-Wallis (KW) states that all observations are i.i.d. according to any continuous distribution, implying in particular that the within-group distributions are all equal.
This actually is a probability model in the sense that it is a well defined set of distributions. Note that the standard null model for one-way ANOVA (all $t_i$ equal in what is formulated in the question, also $E_{ij}$ i.i.d.) is included in this.
Regarding the alternative hypothesis $H_1$ of KW (which I rarely see explicitly stated), one possibility would be to say that if we have distributions $P_i$ within group $i$, at least for some $i\neq j$, $P_i$ is stochastically larger than $P_j$, and otherwise for all pairs $P_i, P_j$ either $P_i=P_j$ or one is stochastically larger than the other. Once more this includes ANOVA in case the $t_i$ are not all the same.
KW certainly respects the level for the stated $H_0$ and is unbiased against $H_1$, but following similar considerations regarding the Wilcoxon/Mann-Whitney test, one could argue that these specifications are incomplete, and a more sophisticated model could be specified that covers an even bigger class of distributions so that KW would still be unbiased, see the discussion here.
So the most correct answer would probably be that the KW-model is a supermodel of the ANOVA one. In that sense, KW covers the ANOVA case, but not the other way round (although if the ANOVA model is true, ANOVA will have the better power). However, KW is often not formulated in terms of a formal model, and the given model is not "generative" in the same sense as the ANOVA model, i.e., one can't simply estimate parameters and then generate data from the estimated model (one could estimate the $P_i$ nonparametrically in principle). Furthermore, note that one could say that ANOVA tests also imply a big nonparametric model, namely "all distributions for which the rejection probability is $\le \alpha$ (significance level) against all distributions for which it is larger", in which case the KW would no longer be a supermodel of ANOVA. The two null hypotheses (and the alternatives by analogy) would have a pretty big intersection, but wouldn't be identical.
